Accessing a firestore stream using streamBuilder in multiple pages not working
Here is a simplified situation: within my appPage, I have profilePage and dashboardPage as the page's body, and they're in an indexed stack.  This appPage has a bottom nav bar to control which body is rendered.
Let's say both bodies profilePage and dashboardPage each have exactly the same code and are listening to the same stream with streamBuilder.  I'm using provider to access my data stream from firestore.
My issue is that only one of the pages will access the data correctly.  The other will just show the loading icon, which happens when the connection state is waiting.  If I get rid of the streamBuilder code on one of the pages entirely and replace it with a blank page, then the app works as expected.  The issue is when trying to have the streamBuilder on multiple pages.
It seems the same stream can't be used in 2 different streamBuilders on different pages, but I don't understand why it isn't working given I tried to centralize my streams with provider.
I've used AI a LOT to try and solve this, but to no avail.  I'm a 16 year old trying to learn to code, and any help is appreciated!
Here is my code for the different pages:
Main:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'Services/ProviderClass.dart';

import 'pages/landing_page.dart';
import 'pages/login_page.dart';
import 'pages/signup_page.dart';
import 'pages/app_page.dart';


void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<FirestoreService>(
          create: (_) => FirestoreService(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: '/AppPage',
        onGenerateRoute: (settings){
          if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null && settings.name != '/LoginPage' && settings.name != '/SignupPage'&& settings.name!='/LandingPage') {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LandingPage());
        }
          switch (settings.name) {
          case '/LandingPage':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LandingPage());
          case '/LoginPage':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage());
          case '/SignupPage':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignupPage());
          case '/AppPage':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AppPage());
          default:
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage());
        }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


App Page code (Page with the bottom nav bar that contains the bodies)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'AppPages/profile_page.dart';
import 'AppPages/dashboard_page.dart';

class AppPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AppPage> createState() => _AppPageState();
}

class _AppPageState extends State<AppPage> {

  int selectedIndex=1;

  void navigateToIndex(int index){
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex=index;
    });
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade200, 
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
            label: "Dashboard"
            ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_sharp),
            label: "Profile"
          )
        ],
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: navigateToIndex,
        fixedColor: Colors.black,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade50,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: selectedIndex,
        children: [
          DashboardPage(),
          ProfilePage(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Dashboard Page
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../Services/ProviderClass.dart';

class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DashboardPage> createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {

  late FirestoreService firestoreService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firestoreService = Provider.of<FirestoreService>(context, listen: false);
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [

                  SizedBox(height:screenSize.height*0.01,),


                  Text(
                    'Your Nutrition History',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 14+screenSize.width*0.03
                      ),
                    ),

                  SizedBox(height:screenSize.height*0.025,),

                  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                    stream: firestoreService.userStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                      }
                      if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
                        return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
                      }
                      //process user data here and return widget based on it
                    }
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: screenSize.height*0.05,),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
  }


Profile page
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../Services/ProviderClass.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  late FirestoreService firestoreService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firestoreService = Provider.of<FirestoreService>(context, listen: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var aspectRatio = screenSize.width/screenSize.height;
    
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Profile",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 14+ screenSize.width*0.01
              ),
            ),

            StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                    stream: firestoreService.userStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                      }
                      if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
                        return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
                      }
                      //process user data here and return widget
                    }
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Provider class
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class FirestoreService {
  final String userUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get userStream {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userUid).snapshots();
  }
}


I tried 2 identical streambuilders on the same page and that worked, which also perplexes me.  When I do 2 identical streambuilders though, one on each page, only one works.

It supposed the DocumentReference.snapshot is a "broadcast" stream so there's no problem listen on the same stream. Looking at your code is not necessary use an IndexedStack when using a BottomNavigationBar, look the example from documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html And the other thing is accessing the Provider in the iniState. Move that to the didChangeDependencies. Hope that helps..

Thanks.  I get where you're coming from with the indexedStack, but when I tried that none of the streamcontrollers worked.  I'm wondering if maybe it was because of when they were being initialized and the initState thing.  Anyways, I found a fix and that was to use a Streamcontroller to broadcast to multiple listeners

The only change needed is to the provider class.  Using a streamcontroller works and allows to broadcast a single stream to many listeners.
Here should be the new firestore provider code, and nothing else should need changing
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class FirestoreService {
  final String userUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final StreamController<DocumentSnapshot> userController = StreamController<DocumentSnapshot>.broadcast();

  FirestoreService() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userUid).snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      userController.add(snapshot);
    });
}

